# Inviteblock Discord.js

Tags: discord, invite

I want to create a bot that blocks invitations.
this is my code

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    const regex = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(discord\.(gg|io|me|li|club)|discordapp\.com\/invite|discord\.com\/invite)\/.+[a-z]/gi;
    if (regex.exec(message.content)) 
        await message.channel.send(
          `${message.author} **você não pode postar link de outros servidores aqui!**\n Vais levar ban se voltares a`
        );
    
  });
```

The problem is that this also blocks the adm invites.

Comment: What is an "admin"? Is it whoever has the administrator permission?

Comment: so... you want it so that if the message author is an admin, don't send the block message? have you tried an if-statement?

Comment: yes  D.Pardal and Klaycon
for the bot not remove the message / link if the administrator is sending

Comment: What *is* an `adm invite`? *admin*, really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the user has the admin role.

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    const regex = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(discord\.(gg|io|me|li|club)|discordapp\.com\/invite|discord\.com\/invite)\/.+[a-z]/gi;

    if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('xxxxx')) {  //replace the Xs with the admin role ID
        if (regex.exec(message.content)) {
           await message.channel.send(
              `${message.author} **você não pode postar link de outros servidores aqui!**\n Vais levar ban se voltares a`
           )
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: i added message.delete() //delete the message
below if (regex.exec(message.content)) {

and above that await message send, then it also deletes the invite